# sending multiple signals at the same time, with short delay

Tags: arduino-uno

Is it possible to do something like this: send a HIGH signal to an output pin, after a 0.33s delay arduino sends HIGH signal to another pin, and after another 0.33s delay, arduino sends signal to third pin. There has to be 90 seconds long high signal for each pin, but with 0.33s delay between each other.

Sooo something like this; start of the high signal on left, stop on right side:

```
pin1: 0 ...... 90.00
pin2: 0.33 ... 90.33
pin3: 0.66 ... 90.66
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Read the BlinkWithoutDelay example and triplicate it.

Comment: Great, thank you! So if I just need to do it once (no need to blink in my case) I can do a while loop with a counter (to 3, for 3 pins), and increment the counter (+set the signal to LOW) when there is 90s (90000ms) from the start.